# Create new key value type from string literals types

Tags: typescript, string-literals

I am looking for a way to create new object type based on values from string literal type. I would like to extract each string literal value and used it as a key in newly create type. So far I am stuck in such solution:

```
export type ExtractRouteParams<T> = string extends T
    ?  Record<string, string>
    : { [k in T] : string | number }

type P = ExtractRouteParams<'Id1' | 'Id2'>
```

It's does what I expect. P has following type

```
type P = {
    Id1: string | number;
    Id2: string | number;
}
```

but unfortunately it throws an error

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.

Solution is done based on that [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUSQBNJkYAeAJWAEcBXYAZxgBo5rHIlHgA%20OAN4AoOKLhRaDZgC52kpjADcIsRM4RuwWRy49lAXyFDQkWHBgBPMHgDiwGIRIQyVJrr5wAvAWKkU5JDoAGyC2HQ0eXmUhS2s4AFUeKC9BcystOAByOiTMxTh9ZVi8RLRGcM0UgTgcstlSqABtAF18wpj0uABhCUxUBup6BSq4JEwAWwzmKGQAczaizviwIj7gBpGxyYB%20WWm5guiAeiO4AGVgPAALGBgwRmkT2YQYK7oAIwA6bAhxo9WkAA3ADWR2wUAgjEYAHdMEFgcZwNB4GQ0FhcHAAIIABQAkoIVKJMkdalBGJlZMIxNS4LN7LI7A5fM5-A1ym4InxlDSxJAZD4nC4esA1gN5Mw2A0ooTDjLiaTGEdpKTcUQKQSeaI6TAGfZHH4KFLuZqwHQdQKDeRlqt%20klJUlpdTDIYhCdzpc4Dc7o8jkEINg4VdITqACwABgjRwATGGY0cAIzxo5hgCsR1Q4zAQTWAFogi80HCc8VFYjTPBigQQDAoDgYJQIGbgNjMLXxoxyAAVfjefZIWZwUCoYiMOCdmXbOQ-KBEch92Zsee8GWyTuD6vAEdwAAGABIBMh0Gg4AB9M4wVswfTSfeH48ttv6I63pBH5IcK-biepRrAxBIOAHwmOAAB84GBYALAgdAqxrOsGybID21cZheGaPYawOQxqVXddhyIUc9wPV9jzPC9YGvF830A1sJn0L9qUnapf3-Gi23QuB5wKFdBHaV1TjOCAgjNBANDgeNZC6bMoSMIhgGwbMJDgBTMChBJKAAGQAWUwCCoHIHFcX4KkxG1eIoCCcgZWpFtXjwzcCPAyDoKxPEZV4AAKazeT6K5ZFsq4WG80QwFo9tZHwata2wetG1QJCOwC5dqQASgwmZ%20wMIwfm4eA6AsnS9JSJBgGhdTtN0tADLxTyUuUfKgkKtBPjMiyPPlJJFWVJJVUyNhqhVIhZEyd4IHeTICjqowGqaqAWvscygnaklOqVQajjACF0AQIJgD61JBuG0bxsm5Q3U1HkAD9rpu267vum7%20KJAAiFayjWnqiA2raduAZ6JoQUckAgeBVMYBBZjGd5dvMCAslehUPrQVVntAuAEc6-6hBmyq5tapaOve7rkbVfqaiSI6xom-QpvOi76YZ6kHtup6sgGinOMwzKCgBoGQbgMGIahmGYDhzJ2ZJ9K5jaTJPiMJ7BOEmBRIAqNJPyqALDmWT5MUvB0DoJAYpV2kFos6qjI8tKVHIAL7K3CCoJgwzPJlULXn83ygupUK2weWDotixCwsS3zkrgFKvH4edonxi3auWxHiagXr%20sOrJjsyGn8jgN0IARIQ45dq3E9W5PVW%206Dfv2gR05Gqns9ZhnmZbh7WcyDGifWzaq92-7ED50GoSFzBobwUX4beskkZTohUbAzuySxouapLwnp-L0nBFJSnxsbunGcPmlW8u9uJagKXuf0XnRn5wXIdHkWxfP1VL-mHm5aAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `PropertyKey` type as generic constraint for `T`:

```
//                               v-----------------v add here
export type ExtractRouteParams<T extends PropertyKey> = string extends T
    ?  Record<string, string>
    : { [k in T] : string | number }

type P = ExtractRouteParams<'Id1' | 'Id2'>
```

Note: `PropertyKey` is just an alias for  `string | number | symbol`.

[Code example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiIZQIYGMYBKEArjMAArY4C2AzgDwAqcoZAdgCa1zlQQqxEAaWCIAfHAC8cWlgCWbAOYtMwTt0YAoODrgB%20HQWC5oHerKgLFAGhnylY7boBccAN5wA2gGs4CuIwAunCuFlZwAD5wbMTUAEbAUHAAvpqaSCg8UuiYOPhEpBRU2HT0AOQAkhwAjGWRcJUcAExlYkA)